# URL Rewriting on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-rewriting, heroku

I have two domain names assigned to my heroku app. I want to make sure that all requests to one domain are permanently redirected to the other domain.

How can I do that on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :ensure_domain

  TheDomain = 'myapp.mydomain.com'

  def ensure_domain
    if request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != TheDomain
      redirect_to TheDomain
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Rails 3, you can take advantage of the [new routing system](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-routing).

```
constraints :host => "invalid.domain.com" do
  match "/*path", :to => proc { |env|
    req = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
    [301, { "Location" => "http://valid.domain.com#{req.fullpath}" }, ["You are being redirected."]] 
  }
end
```

This is just an example. Feel free to refactor the lambda into a custom class.

Comment: I like this, but while it works on every page, it doesn't work for me at "http://localhost:3000/". For some reason match "/*path" doesn't match "/"

Comment: Use the following match `/(*path)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a before_filter in the application controller - Heroku give an example at the bottom of their docs at http://docs.heroku.com/custom-domains or a contraint matched route in your application routes.rb using the redirect method.

John.